# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii and getting the following error when I tried to call

```
$projs = ProjectRegions::model()->with('rEGION')->findAll();
```

```
    CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054     
    Unknown column 't.' in 'on clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT 
    `t`.`PROJECT_ID` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`REGION_ID` AS `t0_c1`, `rEGION`.`REGION_ID` AS `t1_c0`,
    `rEGION`.`REGION_NAME` AS `t1_c1`, `rEGION`.`SUPER_REGION_id` AS `t1_c2`, 
    `rEGION`.`REGION_DESC` AS `t1_c3` FROM `WB_PROJECT_REGIONS` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN    
    `WB_REGIONS` `rEGION` ON (`rEGION`.`REGION_ID`=`t`.``)
```

where I've the following relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
             'pROJECT' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PROJECT', 'PROJECT_ID'),
             'rEGION' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'REGION', 'REGION_ID',),
            );
}
```

There are tables WB_REGION and WB_PROJECT_REGIONS. Both have REGION_ID as column. WB_PROJECT_REGIONS has many WB_PROJECT_REGIONS REGION_ID.

Why it is not joining properly?? I'm missing something?? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Bizzare naming schema, first letter lowercase and rest upcase?

Comment: Actually its a generated code... ;)

Comment: Make sure all tables involved have a primary key.

Comment: Thank you so much DCoder that was the mistake. One of the table was missing primary key...